# DocuSign Connect API -- I need to prepopulate a required custom text field that will be editable by signer

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign Connect API to generate envelopes. I have a tab defined as a custom text field that is marked as required.  I would like to pre-populate its value, and still give the signer the ability to edit the field.

When I populate the field with a string value, it is displayed to the signer but it is not editable.  It is only editable if I fail to populate the field.  I have verified that the 'CustomTabLocked' property is 'false', which I thought would have been enough to ensure the field's edit-ability.

Is the behavior I am seeking supported?

Comment: What does your raw request look like? Please post so we can see the actual XML your code is generating, `CustomTabLocked` should be all you need but maybe there's something wrong with the request body...

Comment: The SOAP trace showed me the way.  I had verified in the debugger that the value for the 'CustomTabLocked' property was false before the API call was made.  But the SOAP trace did not contain an element for 'CustomTabLocked'.  I had to manually set the 'CustomTabLockedSpecified' property to 'true' to get the 'CustomTabLocked' element to show up in the API call, and at that point, the document exhibited the behavior I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an answer for the benefit of the community- when using the DocuSign SOAP API there is an XML property that you need set for certain properties.  In this case to set `CustomTabLocked` to true you also need to set `CustomTabLockedSpecified` property to true.